# Regex for getting strings that contains only the words from the pattern list?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-grep

Consider the following array elements

```
 1.benclinton
 2.clintonharry
 3.harryben
 4.benwill
 5.jasonsmith
 6.smithclinton
```

Assume the pattern list is **ben,harry,clinton**, then the result I should get is

```
1.benclinton  
2.clintonharry  
3.harryben
```

So,essentially the result should contain strings that contains only the words that are in the pattern list. Order is not important

Also, each strings will not be having more than two words. i.e. bensmithwill will never be a case.

Since all my strings are in an array, I thought of using preg_grep in php to do this but i am struck in framing correct regex for this.

what regex can achieve this? Is there any other efficient way apart from regex matching that will do the work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
$names_list = ['benclinton','clintonharry','harryben','benwill','jasonsmith','smithclinton'];
$names = ['ben','harry','clinton'];  

$matches = preg_grep('/('.implode('|',$names).')(?1)/', $names_list);
//-  /(ben|harry|clinton)(?1)/  -- (?1) = recurse capture group 1 

print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => benclinton
    [1] => clintonharry
    [2] => harryben
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6dcceaeaecba550a582e28cc273ea36d35d0fee3)

This requires that at least two of the names (even the same one 2x) match.  But that is kind of a given in this case or everything would match.

If you want to be extra careful, if the `$names` can contain something important to regex, such as `+`,`*`, `\` etc.  you can add this

```
$matches = preg_grep('/('.implode('|',array_map(function($name){return preg_quote($name,'/');},$names)).')(?1)/', $names_list);
```

Comment: This matches `benbenclinton`.  Not sure if the OP expects that a term be an exact match of two substrings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - as does yours. [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08f48602f1d5d7a3bf2b439f3d43c4480a9b0608)

Comment: I can do the same thing with `^` and `$` [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d93bd7b6cc628d0519d077e0ce55019b92415d04) - just saying. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to match array elements which are exact combinations of two keywords.  For a regex approach, we can try taking the cross product of the vector of keyords, and then generate an alternation.  Then, we can use `preg_grep` against your input array to find all matching elements.

```
$array = array("benclinton", "clintonharry", "harryben", "benwill", "jasonsmith", "smithclinton");
$input = array("ben", "harry", "clinton");
$regex = "";
foreach ($input as $term1)  {
    foreach ($input as $term2)  {
        if ($regex != "") $regex .= "|";
        $regex .= $term1.$term2;
    }
}
$regex = "/^(" . $regex . ")$/";
$matches = preg_grep($regex, $array);
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => benclinton
    [1] => clintonharry
    [2] => harryben
)
```

Here is the regex alternation generated by the above script:

```
(benben|benharry|benclinton|harryben|harryharry|harryclinton|clintonben|
    clintonharry|clintonclinton)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way without using for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex.Do with `array_filter` and `strpos`

1. Filter array with respected matching second array the count greater then 1

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c2725624d5b62acc1cec97e3dea231839abde27)

```
<?php
$a = ['benclinton','clintonharry','harryben','benwill','jasonsmith','smithclinton'];
$a2 = ['ben','clinton','harry'];
$res = array_filter($a,function($str="") use($a2){
    $r =array_filter($a2,function($a2str) use($str){
        return strpos($str,$a2str) !== FALSE;
    });
    return count($r) > 1;
});
print_r($res);
?>
```